# Using GitHub with XCode 6.2 causes Storyboard UI Elements to Disappear

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode6, uielement

My partner created a project in XCode and committed it to GitHub. No new changes were made. When either of us tries to bring down the project on our computers, the Storyboard appears to be missing every single UI element (UITextField, UIButton, UILabel, and UITextView). The View Controllers show up, but all of them are empty / blank. In the list view, the elements are there but are grayed out. The project still runs perfectly. If I try to open the Storyboard with an external editor, it still exists as an XML file. Apparently, the elements are still there but they simply fail to show up when the Storyboard is displayed. We are both using the latest XCode, Version 6.2 (6C131e). My partner just upgraded to the latest version of Yosemite a couple of days ago, and I am running OSX 10.9.5. The code is in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the problem happened again, I fixed it the same way as above with the Size Class set to Compact/Any, and this time did a force commit on ALL files even though Git didn't seem to think they needed to be uploaded. That time when I checked the project out again, I could see the UIElements in the Compact/Any without having to change it back to Compact/Any again because it was already showing that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your Size Class enabled. And for size class enabled, you can valid some of the elements and constraint at certain size. If you change the size at the bottom, they will be shown(not grayed out)

Comment: That fixed the immediate problem (I changed the Width Any Height Any to Width Compact Height Any like I had it originally). Then the UIElements showed up again. But when I committed the change and then checked it out again, the problem returned.

Comment: Well, it seems like your or your storyboard or xcodeproj is in gitignore something?

Comment: What does gitignore mean?